# Problema reposicionando img en canvas con keyListener

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, function

Estoy tratando de mover lobo con las flechas del teclado, pero no consigo mas que me recargue la posición de todos los animales, menos del lobo, y lo que quiero es mover el lobo con la flecha que apunta hacia arriba. Ya pondré el resto de teclas cuando consiga hacer que se mueva.
Se que estoy llamando a la función que coloca a todos de nuevo, pero es así como lo vi en el ejemplo del que me guíe.
No se como crear esa función solo cambiando la función moveWolf
Si me dan alguna idea para orientarme, llevo toda la tarde sin ningún éxito.
Gracias.

```js
let finca = document.getElementById('terreno')
parcela = finca.getContext('2d')

document.addEventListener('keydown', moveWolf)//con esto movemos el lobo.

let xWolf = 150
let yWolf = 100

let keys = {//Estas son las variables donde guardamos los keyCode de las teclas que usaremos.
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    DOWN: 40,
    LEFT: 37
}

paseando ()
function paseando (){

    
}


function moveWolf(e) {
    let movement = 60

   
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case keys.UP:
        toDraw (xWolf, yWolf)

        //drawLine(colorcito, x, y, x, y - movement, paper)//debemos de pasar el area de trabajo a la 
                                                         // funcion "drawLine" para que sepa donde dibujar
        yWolf = yWolf - movement//Aqui como que marcamos donde queda la linea, 
                  //recordamos la nueva posicion de "y" al recortarla.
        break    
    }
}


let fondo = {
    url: 'http://i66.tinypic.com/35hpz0k.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let cow = {
    url: 'http://i63.tinypic.com/i5og0i.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let pork = {
    url: 'http://i68.tinypic.com/1emc90.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let chicken = {
    url: 'http://i63.tinypic.com/2woj0g7.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let wolf = {
    url: 'http://i67.tinypic.com/2w4ivwj.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

//let cantidad = myRandom(5, 25)//creo una variable para crear un numero de vacas aleatorio cada vez
//poniendo en el ciclo que genera las vacas (i = 0;i<cantidad;i++) 

fondo.imagen = new Image()//creamos un objeto html llamado imagen
fondo.imagen.src = fondo.url //cargamos la imagen en el nuevo objeto
fondo.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadFondo)//evento que carga la fondo

wolf.imagen = new Image()
wolf.imagen.src = wolf.url
wolf.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadWolf)//evento que carga el lobo

cow.imagen = new Image()
cow.imagen.src = cow.url
cow.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadCow)//evento que carga la vaca


pork.imagen = new Image()
pork.imagen.src = pork.url
pork.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadPork)//evento que carga la vaca

chicken.imagen = new Image()
chicken.imagen.src = chicken.url
chicken.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadChicken)//evento que carga el pollo

function loadWolf() {
    wolf.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}

function loadFondo() {
    fondo.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}

function loadCow() {
    cow.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}


function loadPork() {
    pork.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}

function loadChicken() {
    chicken.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}

function toDraw() {//creamos la funcion para dibujar la imagen en el canvas
    let cantidad = myRandom(5, 10)
    if (fondo.cargaOK == true) {
        parcela.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0)
    }
    if (cow.cargaOK == true) {

       // console.log(cantidad) //para saber el numero de vacas generado                              
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 7)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 7)
            x = x * 60
            y = y * 60

            parcela.drawImage(cow.imagen, x, y)//aqui le ponemos los valores de "x" y "y"
        }

    }
    if (pork.cargaOK == true) {
        //console.log(cantidad)
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 420)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 420)
            parcela.drawImage(pork.imagen, x, y)
        }
    }
    if (chicken.cargaOK == true) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 6)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70

            parcela.drawImage(chicken.imagen, x, y)
        }
    }

    if (wolf.cargaOK == true) {
        let x = (100, 300)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
        let y = (100, 300)
        parcela.drawImage(wolf.imagen, x, y)

    }
}

function myRandom(min, maxi) {
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxi - min)) + min
    return result
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carga de imagenes en canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas height="500" width="500" id="terreno"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITO LA RESPUESTA** Con este cambio ya funciona. Canvas dibuja las cosas una encima de otra, por lo que para mover el lobo, hay que redibujar todo de nuevo en cada movimiento. Más o menos como funcionan los videojuegos, en cada movimiento o acción que se realiza, hay que crear todo de nuevo. Por lo que había que crear la función que re-dibujara todo de nuevo.
Espero sea lo que buscabas.

```js
let finca = document.getElementById('parcela')
let lienzo = finca.getContext('2d')

document.addEventListener("keydown", moverLobo)

let xLobo = 100
let yLobo = 150

let posicionCerdoX = new Array()
let posicionCerdoY = new Array()

let posicionVacaX = new Array()
let posicionVacaY = new Array()

let posicionPolloX = new Array()
let posicionPolloY = new Array()

function moverLobo(e) {
    let movement = 20
    let keys = {
        UP: 38,
        RIGHT: 39,
        DOWN: 40,
        LEFT: 37
    }

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case keys.UP:
            yLobo -= movement
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenMapa, 0, 0)
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenLobo, xLobo, yLobo)
            for (let i = 0; i < posicionCerdoX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenCerdo, posicionCerdoX[i], posicionCerdoY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionVacaX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenVaca, posicionVacaX[i], posicionVacaY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionPolloX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenPollo, posicionPolloX[i], posicionPolloY[i]);
            }
            break

        case keys.RIGHT:
            xLobo += movement
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenMapa, 0, 0)
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenLobo, xLobo, yLobo)
            for (let i = 0; i < posicionCerdoX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenCerdo, posicionCerdoX[i], posicionCerdoY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionVacaX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenVaca, posicionVacaX[i], posicionVacaY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionPolloX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenPollo, posicionPolloX[i], posicionPolloY[i]);
            }
            break

        case keys.DOWN:
            yLobo += movement
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenMapa, 0, 0)
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenLobo, xLobo, yLobo)
            for (let i = 0; i < posicionCerdoX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenCerdo, posicionCerdoX[i], posicionCerdoY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionVacaX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenVaca, posicionVacaX[i], posicionVacaY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionPolloX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenPollo, posicionPolloX[i], posicionPolloY[i]);
            }
            break

        case keys.LEFT:
            xLobo -= movement
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenMapa, 0, 0)
            lienzo.drawImage(imagenLobo, xLobo, yLobo)
            for (let i = 0; i < posicionCerdoX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenCerdo, posicionCerdoX[i], posicionCerdoY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionVacaX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenVaca, posicionVacaX[i], posicionVacaY[i]);
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < posicionPolloX.length; i++) {
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenPollo, posicionPolloX[i], posicionPolloY[i]);
            }
            break
        default:
            alert('¡¡ Para mover al lobo\n solo puede usar las flechas: "> < ^ v " ...!!!' )
    }
}


let mapa = {
    url: "tile.png",
    carga: false
}

let vaca = {
    url: " vaca.png",
    carga: false
}

let cerdo = {
    url: "cerdo.png",
    carga: false
}
let pollo = {
    url: "pollo.png",
    carga: false
}

let lobo = {
    url: "lobo.png",
    carga: false
}


imagenMapa = new Image()
imagenMapa.src = mapa.url
imagenMapa.addEventListener("load", cargaMapa)

imagenVaca = new Image()
imagenVaca.src = vaca.url
imagenVaca.addEventListener("load", cargaVaca)

imagenCerdo = new Image()
imagenCerdo.src = cerdo.url
imagenCerdo.addEventListener("load", cargaCerdo)

imagenPollo = new Image()
imagenPollo.src = pollo.url
imagenPollo.addEventListener("load", cargaPollo)

imagenLobo = new Image()
imagenLobo.src = lobo.url
imagenLobo.addEventListener("load", cargaLobo)


function cargaMapa() {
    mapa = true
    dibujar()
}

function cargaVaca() {
    vaca = true
    dibujar()
}

function cargaCerdo() {
    cerdo = true
    dibujar()
}


function cargaPollo() {
    pollo = true
    dibujar()
}

function cargaLobo() {
    lobo = true
    dibujar()
}

function dibujar() {
    if (mapa) {
        lienzo.drawImage(imagenMapa, 0, 0)

        if (lobo) {
            for (let i = 0; i < myRandom(3, 10); i++) {
                let animalX = myRandom(0, 420)
                let animalY = myRandom(0, 420)
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenLobo, xLobo, yLobo)
            }
        }

        if (vaca) {
            for (let i = 0; i < myRandom(3, 10); i++) {
                let animalX = myRandom(0, 420)
                let animalY = myRandom(0, 420)
                posicionVacaX[i] = animalX
                posicionVacaY[i] = animalY
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenVaca, animalX, animalY)
            }
        }

        if (cerdo) {
            for (let i = 0; i < myRandom(3, 10); i++) {
                let animalX = myRandom(0, 420)
                let animalY = myRandom(0, 420)
                posicionCerdoX[i] = animalX
                posicionCerdoY[i] = animalY
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenCerdo, animalX, animalY)
            }
        }

        if (pollo) {
            for (let i = 0; i < myRandom(3, 10); i++) {
                let animalX = myRandom(0, 420)
                let animalY = myRandom(0, 420)
                posicionPolloX[i] = animalX
                posicionPolloY[i] = animalY
                lienzo.drawImage(imagenPollo, animalX, animalY)
            }
        }
    }
}



function myRandom(min, maxi) {
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxi - min)) + min
    return result
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te falto en la función del lobo poner los randoms, en la función "toDraw" la tienes así:

```
 if (wolf.cargaOK == true) {
    let x = (100, 300)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
    let y = (100, 300)
    parcela.drawImage(wolf.imagen, x, y)

}
```

déjala así:

```
if (wolf.cargaOK == true) {
     let x = myRandom(0, 6)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
        let y = myRandom(0, 6)
        x = x * 70
        y = y * 70
    parcela.drawImage(wolf.imagen, x, y)

}
```

**Solo se mueve lobo**

```
let finca = document.getElementById('terreno')
parcela = finca.getContext('2d')

document.addEventListener('keydown', moveWolf)//con esto movemos el lobo.

let xWolf = 150
let yWolf = 100
//creamos los arrays para guardar la posicion de cada animal
let cantidad = myRandom(5, 10)
var vacas = new Array(cantidad);
var pollos = new Array(cantidad);
var cerdos = new Array(cantidad);


let keys = {//Estas son las variables donde guardamos los keyCode de las teclas que usaremos.
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    DOWN: 40,
    LEFT: 37
}

paseando ()
function paseando (){


}


function moveWolf(e) {
    let movement = 60


    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case keys.UP:
        toDrawWolf ()

        break    
    }
}


let fondo = {
    url: 'http://i66.tinypic.com/35hpz0k.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let cow = {
    url: 'http://i63.tinypic.com/i5og0i.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let pork = {
    url: 'http://i68.tinypic.com/1emc90.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let chicken = {
    url: 'http://i63.tinypic.com/2woj0g7.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

let wolf = {
    url: 'http://i67.tinypic.com/2w4ivwj.png',
    cargaOK: false
}

//let cantidad = myRandom(5, 25)//creo una variable para crear un numero de vacas aleatorio cada vez
//poniendo en el ciclo que genera las vacas (i = 0;i<cantidad;i++) 

fondo.imagen = new Image()//creamos un objeto html llamado imagen
fondo.imagen.src = fondo.url //cargamos la imagen en el nuevo objeto
fondo.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadFondo)//evento que carga la fondo

wolf.imagen = new Image()
wolf.imagen.src = wolf.url
wolf.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadWolf)//evento que carga el lobo

cow.imagen = new Image()
cow.imagen.src = cow.url
cow.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadCow)//evento que carga la vaca


pork.imagen = new Image()
pork.imagen.src = pork.url
pork.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadPork)//evento que carga la vaca

chicken.imagen = new Image()
chicken.imagen.src = chicken.url
chicken.imagen.addEventListener('load', loadChicken)//evento que carga el pollo

function loadWolf() {
    wolf.cargaOK = true

}

function loadFondo() {
    fondo.cargaOK = true
    toDraw()
}

function loadCow() {
    cow.cargaOK = true

}


function loadPork() {
    pork.cargaOK = true
    //toDraw()
}

function loadChicken() {
    chicken.cargaOK = true

}

function toDraw() {//creamos la funcion para dibujar la imagen en el canvas

    if (fondo.cargaOK == true) {
        parcela.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0)
    }
    if (cow.cargaOK == true) {

       // console.log(cantidad) //para saber el numero de vacas generado                              
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 7)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 7)
            x = x * 60
            y = y * 60
//guardamos en el array de la vaca las coordenadas de las que fueron creadas
            vacas[i]= x + "," + y;
            parcela.drawImage(cow.imagen, x, y)//aqui le ponemos los valores de "x" y "y"
        }

    }
    if (pork.cargaOK == true) {
        //console.log(cantidad)
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 420)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 420)
    //guardamos en el array de los cerdos las coordenadas de las que fueron creadas
            cerdos[i]= x + "," + y;
            parcela.drawImage(pork.imagen, x, y)
        }
    }
    if (chicken.cargaOK == true) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {//creo un ciclo para cargar las vacas que queramos
            let x = myRandom(0, 6)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
    //guardamos en el array de los pollos las coordenadas de las que fueron creadas
            pollos[i]= x + "," + y;
            parcela.drawImage(chicken.imagen, x, y)
        }
    }

    if (wolf.cargaOK == true) {

         let x = myRandom(0, 6)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
        parcela.drawImage(wolf.imagen, x, y)

    }
}

function toDrawWolf() {//creamos la funcion para dibujar la imagen en el canvas
    if (fondo.cargaOK == true) {
        parcela.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0)
    }
    //hacemos un barrido de los arrays para redibujarlos en su posición original
    for(let j=0; j < vacas.length; j++){
            //alert(vacas[j]);
            var valorV = vacas[j].split(',');
            var valorP = pollos[j].split(',');
            var valorC = cerdos[j].split(',');
            parcela.drawImage(cow.imagen, parseInt(valorV[1]), parseInt(valorV[0]))
            parcela.drawImage(chicken.imagen, parseInt(valorP[1]), parseInt(valorP[0]))
            parcela.drawImage(pork.imagen, parseInt(valorC[1]), parseInt(valorC[0]))
    }

    if (wolf.cargaOK == true) {

         let x = myRandom(0, 6)//creamos posicion de una vaca dentro del cmapa
            let y = myRandom(0, 6)
            x = x * 70
            y = y * 70
        parcela.drawImage(wolf.imagen, x, y)

    }
}
function myRandom(min, maxi) {
    let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxi - min)) + min
    return result
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero si hago eso, elimino el lobo del canvas.                           Necesito crear la función que mueva al animal

Comment: Checa el código que te pongo, a mi si me funciona así tal cual lo pongo

Comment: Gracias, si que funciona, pero como pone en el titulo, lo que quiero es mover con la flecha que apunta hacia arriba es solo el lobo, no recargar la posición de todos. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Ya te lo deje que solo se mueva el lobo, solo se cambia la primera vez de posición los demás animales, pero después de  la primera solo el lobo se mueve, cualquier duda estoy a tus ordenes

Comment: Pues a mi no me funciona, ni siquiera se ven los animales. Gracias por el apoyo, seguiré intentándolo.